# Добавление данных из нескольких массивов в один

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

задача очень простая

```
    <?php
    $cpModels_79 = [
        ['cp7937', '431', 'Cisco CP-7937'],
        ['cp7940', '8', 'Cisco CP-7940'],
        ['cp7941', '115', 'Cisco CP-7941'],
    ];
    $cpModels_net = [
        ['ipv4', '172.17.42.200', '24'],
        ['ipv4', '72.17.42.13', '24'],
        ['ipv4', '72.17.42.24', '24'],
    ];
    
    $cpModels = [];
    
    foreach ($cpModels_79 as $items) {
        $cpModels[] = $items;
    }
    
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($cpModels_net as $items) {
        array_push($cpModels[$i], $items);
        $i++;
    }
    
    
    print_r($cpModels);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => cp7937
            [1] => 431
            [2] => Cisco CP-7937
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ipv4
                    [1] => 172.17.42.200
                    [2] => 24
                )

        )
```

В целом с таким выходом тоже можно работать, но хотелось бы получить как ниже, array_push($cpModels[$i], list($a) = $items) пробовал, но выход получился идентичный выше

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => cp7937
            [1] => 431
            [2] => Cisco CP-7937
            [3] => Array
            [4] => ipv4
            [5] => 172.17.42.200
            [6] => 24
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

 $cpModels_79 = [
    ['cp7937', '431', 'Cisco CP-7937'],
    ['cp7940', '8', 'Cisco CP-7940'],
    ['cp7941', '115', 'Cisco CP-7941'],
  ];
$cpModels_net = [
    ['ipv4', '172.17.42.200', '24'],
    ['ipv4', '72.17.42.13', '24'],
    ['ipv4', '72.17.42.24', '24'],
];

$results = [];
foreach($cpModels_79 as $key => $value) {
    $results[] = array_merge($value, $cpModels_net[$key]);
}

print_r($results);
```

[Результат:](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=jZHPC4IwFMfvgv_DOwgqmLS5WNGvQ-egu4gMWylZjs2CiP73mrmi0aFd3nj78Hlf3mZLUQrXcR2vEOtmy2uV0wnMIXUd6E_qF4JOEupH4JME6bKqVNHAajPo-llkw2SoqbGFPrs_0E6I0MiG0RvOpq_6iXjirZ2xEhfSmSiOEY0JjvGwS4GJNdWQbxAl_3GYWJwJ1seTXJ3rVulk5mXXSM6KMvjaLlPgHfgV5gvwLqw-8xBun8FGk2ZPEZOSXfMjl3sevNjoew2pNmVhP-6uf1JfhKxObS4DIwunDw%2C%2C&v=8.1.3)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => cp7937
        [1] => 431
        [2] => Cisco CP-7937
        [3] => ipv4
        [4] => 172.17.42.200
        [5] => 24
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => cp7940
        [1] => 8
        [2] => Cisco CP-7940
        [3] => ipv4
        [4] => 72.17.42.13
        [5] => 24
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => cp7941
        [1] => 115
        [2] => Cisco CP-7941
        [3] => ipv4
        [4] => 72.17.42.24
        [5] => 24
    )
```

)